# LIB library /EXTRACT:member /OUT:objectfile

Tags: visual-studio

Where do I run this syntax? There's no command line on Visual Studio. I know this is a simple question but so far I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, after installation of Visual Studio, you have a submenu entry inside the Microsoft Visual Studio program group called `Visual Studio Tools`. In this submenu you could find a couple of `Command Prompt for ...` menu that launch a command window with specific path set to the Tools installed with Visual Studio, including the LIB tool

For example, this is the command executed by one of mine menu entries

```
%comspec% /k ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat""  x86_amd64
```

Comment: thank you. so under that command prompt it woulb something like this? 

`LIB C:\Users\Samuel Pedro\Desktop\ISRProject\bioPlux_API\Original_files\BioPlux.lib /EXTRACT:Dev.obj /OUT:Dev.obj`

Comment: Yes, as you can see, the command prompt executes a batch file copied in the installation folder of Visual Studio. You could open it and see how various PATH settings are applied to the current command window. This result in the LIB command available. Then is up to you to pass the right arguments.

Comment: it returns: LINK : warning LNK4014: cannot find member object Dev

Comment: Are you sure to have a member called `Dev`. Try with `LIB /LIST:yourlibraryhere.lib`

Comment: Thanks, the /LIST helped. Now that I have the file.obj is there a way to view the source?

Comment: Can't help on this. I suppose no, but I think you should try asking a new question